# Is it possible to have a merge module targetting the GAC?

Tags: wix, wix3, wix3.5

I'm trying to figure out the best way to create a merge module that installs .NET assemblies. I'd like to allow the user of the module to specify a folder or the GAC.

I found that to allow targeting of a folder I should use  and to install in the GAC I have to set Assembly=".net" and KeyPath="yes" in the File tags.

It it possible to merge these two or do I have to create two different merge modules?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is roughly how you'll have to do it:

```
<ComponentGroup Id="Assembly1">
 <Component Id="gac_Assembly1" Guid="*">
  <Condition><[CDATA[INSTALLGAC]]></Condition>
  <File Id="fil_Assembly1" . . . />
 </Component>
 <Component Id="file_Assembly1" Guid="*">
  <Condition><[CDATA[Not INSTALLGAC]]></Condition>
  <File Id="fil_Assembly1" . . . />
 </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

You should always KeyPath the one file under your component.  INSTALLGAC is a public property that the MSM-includer can set.